# C++ callback function issue

Tags: c++

I have written a simple C++ program to accept a callback.

**What callback does?** the callback is the second argument of the main function and it simply returns a string, that string is then inserted into a .txt file by main function.

**What is the error?** Visual studio 2013 throws this error:

```
error C2664: 'void WriteToFile(std::string,std::string (__cdecl *)(std::string))' : cannot convert argument 2 from 'std::string' to 'std::string (__cdecl *)(std::string)'
```

Here is the **code**:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void WriteToFile(string filename, string (*f)(string) )
{
    ofstream FileProcessor;

    FileProcessor.open(filename, ios::app);

    FileProcessor << &f << endl;

}

string Printer(string Content)
{
    return Content;
}

int main()
{

    WriteToFile("test.txt", Printer("exampleText"));


}
```

Answer (score 1):

`WriteToFile` is expecting the second argument to be a function pointer, not the result of a function call. Change the call to look like this:

```
WriteToFile("test.txt", Printer);
```

Still, it doesn't make much sense, because `&f` is the address of the function, so it'll just print some hex value. You probably want to call the function pointer:

```
FileProcessor << (*f)("exampleText") << endl;
```

For passing the argument, you have two options. Vinayak Garg listed one, which is to add a third argument to `WriteToFile`. The other one is to use `std::bind`.

```
WriteToFile("test.txt", std::bind(&Printer, "exampleText"));
```

In the latter case it will not look like it takes an argument however. Your definition of `WriteToFile` should look like this (untested):

```
void WriteToFile(string filename, const std::function<string()> &f )
{
    ...
    FileProcessor << f() << endl;
}
```

Comment: so how should then I pass the argument? Like the one happens in Javascript or PHP?

Comment: Not sure if you meant a higher level function or just an extra argument. Explained the former

Comment: Well, I did say untested. But that error is weird, sure those () are normal () and not some special characters?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK `Printer("exampleText")` is passed incorrectly. The second argument of function `WriteToFile` accepts a pointer to function. So just pass the function `Printer`.

The argument for the passed function pointer should be sent as different argument.

Something like-

```
void WriteToFile(string filename, string (*f)(string), string mystring )
{
    ofstream FileProcessor;

    FileProcessor.open(filename, ios::app);

    FileProcessor << f(mystring) << endl;

}
```

and then called like

```
WriteToFile("test.txt", Printer, "exampleText");
```